# Orthogonality with respect to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider two vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Obviously, $x^\top y = 0$ implies that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal. Now, let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix. What is the meaning of $$x^\top A y = 0$$? Does this imply orthogonality of $x$ and $y$ with respect to something?

Comment: Note:  if $A$ is the zero matrix, $x^TAy=0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Obviously, this means that $x$ is orthogonal to the image of $y$ under $A$. I was wondering if there are more meanings behind it.

Comment: Yes, as you said in the previous comment, $x^tAy = 0$ means that $x$ is orthogonal to some linear combination of the **columns** of $A$, but also we that $0 = x^tAy = (A^tx)^ty$, that is, $y$ is orthogonal to some combination of the **rows** of $A$.

Comment: If $x^TAy = 0$, then we can say that $x,y$ are orthogonal relative to the [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) induced by $A$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1364346/293177?